# The conversion of type 'TimeSpan' to type 'Date' is not valid.vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have a problem with The conversion of type 'TimeSpan' to type 'Date'
if someone can help me this my code and the error :

```
Public Function combine(ByVal dateonly As DateTime, ByVal timeonly As DateTime)



    date_Combine = DateTime.Parse(dateonly)
    Time_Combine = DateTime.Parse(timeonly)
    date_Combine.AddHours(Double.Parse(timeonly.Hour))
    date_Combine.AddMinutes(Double.Parse(timeonly.Minute))
    date_Combine.AddSeconds(Double.Parse(timeonly.Second))

    Return date_Combine
 End Function


For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
        start = combine(row.Cells(1).Value, row.Cells(2).Value)
        marche = combine(row.Cells(3).Value, row.Cells(4).Value)
        diff = marche.Subtract(start).Hours
        total += diff
    Next
    MessageBox.Show(total)
    TextBox7.Text = total
```

the error :

The conversion of type 'TimeSpan' to type 'Date' is not valid.

I want to know what's the wrong

NB: in my database , DateStartTasck are of type Date(sql) with this form (yyyy-MM-dd) , and TimeStartTasck are of type Time ( sql) with this form 00:00:00

Comment: That's a lot of (badly formatted) code - where *exactly* did the problem occur?

Comment: And *please* use parameterized SQL instead of putting values into the SQL string itself...

Comment: I have probelm in this part start = combine(row.Cells(1).Value, row.Cells(2).Value)
        marche = combine(row.Cells(3).Value, row.Cells(4).Value)

Comment: [`DateTime.AddHours`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addhours.aspx): "Returns a **new** DateTime that adds the specified number of hours to the value of this instance." (My emphasis). Similarly for the other `AddXXX` methods.

Comment: what's the solution of that ?!!

Answer (score 0):

This is a double question;

You allready asked it here: [manipulate DataGridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18078278/manipulate-datagridview/18079370#18079370)

I've asked you to strip out the non relative stuff, and you also did not do anything with the previous question.

Comment: thank you , i strip out what you see ! , for the last question i asked how to manipulate dataGridView and I have problem in this manipulation if you have any proposition i will be gratfull